# iOS 13: Scroll view inside navigation controller won't go under the status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I wanted to make a custom scroll view usable from SwiftUI that would allow me to set the scroll position. I got half way through and ran into an issue with the scroll view not flowing under the status bar properly when scrolled.

The problem looks like this:

[image]

When testing to see what's wrong, I made a storyboard based comparison project that has no code at all, just a structure exactly identical to what I have in code. The result then looks like this, which is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

It seems as if the root view controller view does not reach all the way to the top, but I can't figure out why. All the other automatic scroll inset magic works as it should.

Here's the code I have, you can just make a new project with SwiftUI in Xcode 11 and paste this in to ContentView.swift.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class UIScrollableViewController: UIViewController {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let contentController: UIViewController

    init(contentController: UIViewController) {
        self.contentController = contentController

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // Add child controller
        scrollView.addSubview(contentController.view)
        addChild(contentController)

        let contentView = contentController.view!

        // Constrain scroll view
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        // Constrain child view to scroll view
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        // Constrain width of child view to width of self.view, NOT scroll view
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

class ScrollableNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationBarDelegate {
}

struct ScrollableNavigationViewController<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ScrollableNavigationController

    let hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>
    let scrollableContainer: UIScrollableViewController!

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
        scrollableContainer = UIScrollableViewController(contentController: hostingController)

        scrollableContainer.title = "Scrollable"
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ScrollableNavigationViewController>) -> ScrollableNavigationController {
        let navigationController = ScrollableNavigationController(rootViewController: scrollableContainer)

        navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        return navigationController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ navigationController: ScrollableNavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ScrollableNavigationViewController>) {
    }
}

struct ScrollableNavigationView<Content: View>: View {
    var content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollableNavigationViewController {
            content
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Test

struct BoxView: View {
    var colors: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .orange, .pink, .yellow]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0 ..< 20) { i in
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(self.colors[i % 5])
                    .padding()
                    .frame(height: 130)
                Text("\(i)")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollableNavigationView {
            BoxView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the scene delegate, which causes the entire view hierarchy to be wrapped inside a `UIHostingController` that does it's own inset magic that nested SwiftUI controllers seem to be able to avoid. To demonstrate this, I came up with a slightly hacky solution.

Replace this:

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

with:

```
window.rootViewController = MyHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

`MyHostingController`looks like this:

```
class MyHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        view.subviews[0].frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    }
}
```

As of iOS 13.1, it seems you should really only try to integrate SwiftUI between two layers of UIKit, not the other way around. SwiftUI contains too much undocumented magic in its internals.